# Standard Error of Ridge regression

Tags: inference, standard-error, ridge-regression

Why is it advised to use bootstrap for finding the SE for the ridge regression estimator? [image]

Using the above formula, we can get the SE much faster than bootstrap. But all the research papers in literature has used the bootstrap method, which is time-consuming. The above formula is from [Lecture notes on ridge regression](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf).
I have tried both methods in R, and they give different values.
Please explain what is the disadvantage of using the formula method.

Comment: Those formulae are for a given lambda. Usually, we use the data to select lambda. The bootstrap would propagate uncertainty in lambda to the variance terms.

Comment: Once we select the best lambda using cross-validation (the one with minimum mean squared error (MSE)), can't we use the formula? I use cv.glmnet function in R for cross validation.

Comment: No, because lambda selected by cross-validation is an estimate by itself which has statistical uncertainty in it.